# Android ServiceConnection - EBADF (Bad file number)

Tags: android, serviceconnection

Could not cleanup output stream : java.net.SocketException: shutdown failed: EBADF (Bad file number)

has anyone got this, any work around to get rid of this exception ?

Comment: stacktrace and some code would be nice

Comment: this happens some times when the output is already cleared or the socket it attached to is already closed.

Answer (score 0):

This could mean you don't have permission to write to the file or it's read only.